# SPSite.AllWebs vs SPSite.OpenWeb

Tags: development, csom

What are the benefits of using `SPSite.AllWebs` over `SPSite.OpenWeb` and vice versa when it comes to `using`-statements and/or checking if a `SPWeb` with a specific URL already exists?

Comment: So youalso want to check if a site already exists or not?

Answer (score 1):

SPSite.AllWebs Gets the collection of all Web sites that are contained within the site collection, including the top-level site and its subsites and SPSite.OpenWeb returns the specified Web site from the site collection.

So SPSite.AllWebs returns all sites and SPSite.OpenWeb will return the specific website in your site collection.  There is no difference in using - statements.

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
using (SPWeb oWebsite = collWebsite[i])
```

For Spsite.OpenWeb

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(strUrl))
{
    using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("MyWebSite/MySubSite"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Website: " + oWebsite.Url);
    }
}
```